# Send JSON Encoded PHP Variable to JavaScript onblur Event

Tags: javascript, php, json

I am trying to dynamically generate a set of input fields on my PHP page when a user pulls focus from a single preexisting input text field.  Essentially, I'd like to use onblur to send both the value of this initial field and an array I've retrieved from MySQL to a JS function, which will then use that information to determine which input fields are needed and generate them.

I am able to JSON encode the array without any difficulty:

```
$mysqli_equations = collect_all_formulas();
$equations = array();
while($row = $mysqli_equations->fetch_assoc()) {
    $equations[] = $row;
}

$js_array = json_encode($equations);
```

If I echo the $js_array string at this point, it looks good to me...

> [{"BlackboxEquationId":"1","FindingVariable":"a","Equation":"a = ( 2.0
> / t ) * ( ( ( xf - xo ) / t ) - vo
> )"},{"BlackboxEquationId":"2","FindingVariable":"a","Equation":"a = (
> vf ^2.0 - vo ^2.0 ) / ( 2.0 * ( xf - xo )
> )"},{"BlackboxEquationId":"3","FindingVariable":"a","Equation":"a = (
> vf - vo ) / t"}, ... ]

But if I try to send it with onblur (note, this is a line within a php echo):

```
> <input type="text" id="known_variable" name="known_variable"
> onblur="build_known_vars(this.value, ' . $js_array . ')"
> onfocus="remove_vars()" />
```

I get an unexpected end of input.  I believe this is because the first time we hit double quotes, we take this to be the end of the string, but then the input stream just keeps spitting out the rest of the string:

```
<input type="text" id="known_variable" name="known_variable" onblur="build_known_vars(this.value, [{" BlackboxEquationId":" 1"," FindingVariable":" a", etc etc
```

I've tried and failed at manipulating the data to make it happy, but even replacing all double quotes results in a different unexpected input message, I assume due to the rest of the nonsense characters in the string I'm sending.

Is my best bet here to use JSON.parse prior to sending?  If so, where / how would I do this, since I'm attempting to send the string to a JS function directly from the input field?  Or am I way off, and there's another way I should be passing this along altogether?

Very inexperienced, and perhaps I'm approaching this the wrong way altogether, so more than open to advice if that's the case.  There seem to be similar questions already out there, but I'm not finding any that specifically address this situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that the file your code is in is a .php file, so this should resolve your issue:

```
<script>let jsArray = <?php print $js_array ?></script>
```

Now remove the 2nd parameter from your JS function, and in that function just reference jsArray instead.

JSON is an object, so in script tags it does not need to be wrapped in single quotes.

The variable is now globally scoped (you're a beginner so don't worry about that right now), so you can simply reference it in your function.

HTH